# Change font size inside a frame with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<frameset cols="*" rows="48,100%" border="0" frameborder="yes" bordercolor="black">
    <frame name="header" src="bar.jsp" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="body" src="body.jsp" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame>
</frameset>
</HTML>
```

Inside frame body I have the page body.jsp:

```
<table id="people" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0">
<tr class='list'>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class='list'>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to change the font size for all rows inside table?

Comment: What HTML standard are you using? You're missing a doctype. If you're using HTML 5 there are ways of transporting data between the hosting page and the frame, that is the proper way to handle it. Trying to manipulate a frame's inner html is a security violation because it is not easy for a browser to determine if the frame is being hosted by you or if you are trying to execute a cross-site scripting attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your frames are the same domain so thats good. What you can do is insert a CSS file onto your frames using javascript, and then target whatever you want.

Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) question:

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "style.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['body'].document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

and in that css file add something like:

```
#people tr{
   font-size:12pt;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what I need is: change style from a remote website, injecting a new style.

So I need to override the style for all tags like: `<tr class='list'>`


Thanks!

Comment: And I need to overwrite it without creating a style file on the server.

Comment: you can't inject javascript cross domain on an iframe